# Creating a help book for Mac app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've taken a look at the Apple docs for creating help files that use the built-in help menu at [the Apple doc site.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_concepts/apple_help_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH205-BABIGCDB) I think I have a pretty good grasp on the concepts, as long in the tooth as they may be. I searched a bit further on the web for a shorter tutorial-ish way to do something, in my opinion, rather simple. I found a bunch and most describe a process found [here](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/02/help-how-to-integrate-helpfile-in-my.html).

However, for the life of me I can't get it working on 10.9 using Xcode 5.0.2. I have created the help files, added the Apple hooks in the header of the html file, run the Help Indexer, added the files to Xcode, and added both CFBundleHelpBookFolder and CFBundleHelpBookName to my Info.plist. The help menu item opens Help, however it does not open my help file. I get a page that says "The selected topic is currently unavailable."

Does anyone out there have a better tutorial to create a very simple help book and get it working?

Comment: Note that Help Books are broken by sandboxing on OS X 10.8+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your confusion. When I first tried to add a Help Book to my application, it never seemed to work, but eventually using the `Apple Help Programming Guide` it got there. I found I had to actually install the app into /Applications before the system would find it. (I am not sure if this is strictly necessary).

NOTE I am not sure the link you listed is correct. The `Apple Help Programming Guide` states:-

```
Select the help bundle in the Add Files dialog and click Add.
Select the “Create Folder References for any added folders” radio button and click Add
```

PS I suggest you examine the `Package Contents` of your app, and check that it actually does contain the Help Book.

Comment: Thanks Milliways. I missed checking the "Create Folder References for any added folder" radio button. Thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: I assume it uses launch services normal logic for awareness of things specified in the plist... either in one if the applications folders or if you launch the app